# String is adding special characters

Tags: c, arrays, string

I started following tutorials on C, and then I (from scratch) attempted to do a program where the program chooses a word and you have to guess letters, until you find out the word or run out of attempts.

But I am stuck at the string part, really weird :

```
srand(time(NULL));
char pWord[6][15] = {"chocolate","peanut","bowling","helicopter","school","controller"}; // Possible words
int repeat=0;
int rNum = rand()%6;
char solution[strlen(pWord[rNum])];
while(repeat<strlen(pWord[rNum])) {
    solution[repeat]=pWord[rNum][repeat];repeat++;  
}
printf("Answer : %s", solution); printf("\n");
printf("R Answer : %s", pWord[rNum]); printf("\n");
printf("R length : %i", strlen(pWord[rNum])); printf("\n");
strcpy(solution,pWord[rNum]);
```

For bowling it is fine, but for others it adds weird special characters at random.
I have no idea why this is happening ( i come from java, somewhere lazy and easy ).

Comment: The `solution` array is not null terminated.

Comment: Note that "not null terminated" is the first place to start with any C question that involves added characters. Array bounds error and/or pointer math error are the next thing to look for. Those three account for a huge percentage of C coding errors... which is part of why Java was explicitly designed to prevent them from being possible. (At least, not in the simple forms C is most subject to.)

Comment: Also not there is no such thing as special characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, the string ends with null character `'\0'`. So when you declare the character string `solution`, you need to add one to the length of the char array since `strlen()` function doesn't count the null character at the end.

```
char solution[strlen(pWord[rNum])+1];
```

Then after the while loop, you need to assign the `'\0'` to the last element of the char array:

```
while(repeat<strlen(pWord[rNum])) {
    solution[repeat]=pWord[rNum][repeat];
    repeat++;  
}
solution[repeat]='\0';
```

A better way to do this string copying is to use `strcpy()` function instead of the while loop:

```
strcpy(solution, pWord[rNum]);
```

This way you don't have to assign the null character to the last character. This function does it for you.